# How to gradient fill custom UIView using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-view

I have a custom triangle `UIView` which I want to fill with custom gradient color.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let widerStartingPoint = CGFloat(240)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX - widerStartingPoint, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + widerStartingPoint, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY))
    context.closePath()

    let colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor ,thirdColor.cgColor] as CFArray

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.5 ,1.0]

    let startPoint = CGPoint.zero
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height)

    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace,
                              colors: colors as CFArray,
                              locations: colorLocations)!

    // I need to find a way to change below color with gradient color
    context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.60)
    context.fillPath()
}
```

I tried to find other `setFillColor` methods, but they are only allowing assigning single color.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+gradient+fill+path).

Comment: @rmaddy Found a solution. I was missing clipping and also needed to use context.drawLinearGradient instead of setFillColor. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `setFillColor` I used `context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: [])` also added clipping to the path. So working code is below!:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let widerStartingPoint = CGFloat(240)

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX - widerStartingPoint, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX + widerStartingPoint, y: rect.maxY))
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY))
    context.closePath()

    // This was missing!
    context.clip()

    let colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor ,thirdColor.cgColor] as CFArray

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.5 ,1.0]

    let startPoint = CGPoint.zero
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height)

    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace,
                              colors: colors as CFArray,
                              locations: colorLocations)!

    // Also used this method
    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: [])
    context.fillPath()
}
```